# How concatenate path (read in file) and a string in bash?

Tags: bash, carriage-return

I'm in CentOs8. I have a file with lot of uri :

```
/var/log/toto/*.log
/var/log/tata/*.log
```

I use `while read line` to read line and add a string in end of each path :

```
#!/bin/bash

    while read line
    do
        echo "$line""-20201117.gz"
    done < "/opt/scripts/folders.conf"
```

Output is :

```
-20201117.gzo/*.log
-20201117.gza/*.log
```

Why ? I would like : `/var/log/toto/*.log-20201117.gz` Somebody can help me ?

Answer (score 2):

I can duplicate this using a file with Windows style CRLF line endings on a Linux system. Run your file through `dos2unix` or the like to convert the line endings to LF ones.

Comment: I did the same test and got the same result. Using `while IFS=$' \t\n\r' read -r line` could be an alternative.